# what if mixpanel alias method not called on signup?

Tags: analytics, mixpanel

I have implemented mixpanel after 6 month from web-app launch. Till that date i have 6k user who already signed up. so is there any impact on mix panel data(people profile) for not setting alias method on signup for that user? is this cause to **one user may have multiple distinct id or vice versa ?**